# Stretched plots in R when plotting multiple figures to PDF

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I'm trying to create a pdf with multiple plots in pdf, when I create a pdf with 2 X 2 plots the plots are square and looks nice:

```
pdf(file=paste0("Test.pdf"), paper = "a4")
par(mfrow=(c(2,2)), omi=c(0,0,0,0), mar=c(2, 2, 0, 0))
for (i in 1:4)
{
    plot(1:10)
}
dev.off()
```

However if I try to generate a pdf with 3 rows and 2 columns the plots are not square. The plots seems to be stretched so that the entire 3 x 2 matrix of plots are squared:

```
pdf(file=paste0("Test 2.pdf"), paper = "a4")
par(mfrow=(c(3,2)), omi=c(0,0,0,0), mar=c(2, 2, 0, 0))
for (i in 1:6)
{
    plot(1:10)
}
dev.off()
```

How do I get the individual plots to be square in a configuration where the number of rows and columns are not equal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: set the size of the device?

Comment: Change the aspect with `asp=1`?

Comment: But I want the size of the device to be like an A4 paper, as specified in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly you can use [layout](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/layout.html) instead

```
pdf(file=paste0("Test 2.pdf"), paper = "a4")
layout(matrix(1:6, 3, 2, byrow = TRUE), respect = TRUE)
par(omi=c(0,0,0,0), mar=c(2, 2, 0, 0))
for (i in 1:6)
{
    plot(1:10)
}
dev.off()
```